# Who operates a 707 with Boeing factory livery?

Tags: livery, boeing-707

I have just seen a 707 depart from HTDA Dar es Salaam that has the tail painted with the Boeing colors. Any idea of who the plane belongs to?

Livery like this one:

[image: 777 in Boeing colors]

Obviously 707 instead of 777 painted on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Official airplane of Democratic Republic of Congo**

Today, the [Democratic Republic of Congo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Republic_of_the_Congo) uses a [B707-138B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707), registered 9Q-CLK: LK for Laurent Kabila.

[Laurent Kabila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent-D%C3%A9sir%C3%A9_Kabila) has been Congo's President until his assassination (he was succeeded by his son).

This is an airplane with a [long history](http://www.adastron.com/707/qantas/VH-EBG.htm) (and some controversy). She has now `707` painted on the tail, but not the `Boeing` markings. Thanks to our friends at [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/) several pictures are available:

[image]
<sup>(source: [Airliners.net, Mark. Szemberski](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing-707-138B/2532333/&sid=2cb052bc2441fd592494c5145153691e))</sup>

Once this a/c had no logo at all, here in 2008:

[image]
<sup>(source: [Airliners.net, Weimeng](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Boeing-707-138B/1384256/&sid=2cb052bc2441fd592494c5145153691e))</sup>

On Youtube too: [B707 9Q-CLK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rrC3Zwn5vs) .

**Qantas in the past**

Back in 1959 when it entered service at Qantas as [VH-EBG](http://www.aussieairliners.org/b-707q/vh-ebg/vhebg.html), the first B707 with a 5th engine in a pod-pak:

[image]
<sup>(source: [Qantas Heritage Collection](http://www.aussieairliners.org/b-707q/vh-ebg/4605.234.html))</sup>

More on the curious [engine exhaust and the pod-pak](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/what-is-a-pod-pak).

Comment: Side question, but what the heck is up with that engine on left of the last picture? It looks totally different.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg The trick is that on the right it's no engine at all. It's a Pod-Pak, an encasement for spare engine carried just in case ground crew needs one.

Comment: @Agent_L: The [same pod-pak](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/d0/91/0f/d0910f38cad0c77a102ecd571249ac2e.jpg) with the crew. [Another picture of the pod-pak](https://books.google.com/books?id=G1ujXqwsDcUC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14). And this [overall view showing the location](https://books.google.com/books?id=0SoDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140). Hey this was 1959! Still flying after 56 years, albeit without the spare engine.

Comment: But what's up with the engine on the left, why so many exhaust holes?

Comment: @Alexus: This is explained by DeltaLima in the [linked question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19566/what-is-a-pod-pak): It's for noise reduction.

Comment: @Alexus, it's not an engine, it's a missile pod ;-)

Comment: What I don't get is why they still fly the boeing 707

Comment: @Ethan Because the DRC is a fairly poor country and doesn't have enough money to fly its president around in something more modern? It has an economy slightly smaller than Idaho's -- can you imagine the Governor of Idaho flying around in, say, a 737-800 series?

Comment: "Quantas" means Qantas?

Comment: Thanks, kevin, I was thinking that was an odd line of succession... :/

Comment: kevin and @Him, thanks!